# Jquery Webcam Plugin upload image to server using java

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to know if there is a way to upload an image to the server using java. I am using jquery webcam plugin and they have a script that does this however i am not using php i am using SpringMVC (java).

I am not sure if there is a way to configure a SpringMVC project to use php and java together. This is what i have so far:

**Code**

```
var pos = 0, ctx = null, saveCB, image = [];
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', 320);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', 240);
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);

var saveCB = function (data) {
    var col = data.split(';');
    var img = image;
    for (var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
        var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
        img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
        img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
        img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
        img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
        pos += 4;
    }

    if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240) {
        ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
        foto = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $("#photo").val(foto);
        pos = 0;
    }
};
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
document.createElement("canvas");

$("#canvas").hide();

$("#camera").webcam({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        useMicrophone: false,
        mode: "callback",
        swffile: "resources/swf/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
        quality:85,

        onSave: saveCB,
        onCapture: function () {
            $("#camera").hide();
            webcam.save(//need a java function to upload to server );
            $("#canvas").show();                 

        },

        debug: function (type, string) {
            $("#status").html(type + ": " + string);
        }

}); 



$('#upload').click(function () {
    webcam.capture(); 
    return false;
});

$('#retake').click(function () {
    $("#canvas").hide();
    $("#camera").show();
    return false;
});


window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
        image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);

    }

    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After drawing the image to the canvas
Use `canvas.toDataURL()` - returns base64 encoded data of the image as a request parameter

then in the back-end, use `Base64.decodeBase64(String data)` to decode the encoded data to byte array:

```
//@RequestParam data

//remove mimeType declaration in the data string first

String byteStr = data.split(",")[1];


//get the byte array of the data

byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(byteStr);
```